# How to Transfer multiple files from Linux server to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can someone let me know how to transfer multiple files from Linux server to AWS?

Comment: Why not `tar`, `zip` and transfer using `scp`?

Comment: AWS is comprised of many services. Which specific service are you trying to transfer the files to? You tagged the question with S3 so I assume you are trying to transfer files to S3. You should install the AWS CLI tool and use it to copy files to S3. https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to copy the data to Amazon S3, the easiest method is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), either:

- `aws s3 cp --recursive` or
- `aws s3 sync`

The `sync` command **automatically recurses sub-directories** and is generally a better option because it can be re-run and only copies files modified or added since the previous execution. Thus, it can be used to **continue the copy after a failure**, or the next day when new files have been adeed.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using scp or sftp to transfer files. If your local machine is a linux one, you can use the console, otherwise putty in a windows machine.

Comment: I have tried like this . aws s3 cp file1.txt file2.txt s3://tempdata/20170803/            I have received an error message like "Unknown options: s3://tempdata/20170803/". I am able to transfer a directory to s3 where as I am unable to transfer specified files to s3